# How do I create report-like data tables in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In the past I have created websites that extract data from a database and format it using tables.

Now, I am trying to do the same thing but with Excel, and I'm lost.  I am used to using SQL commands to extract data from given fields and then sort/manipulate it.

Currently, I am able to print a report that provides me with an Excel spreadsheet full of raw data, but I would like to make my life easier and organize it into a report.

The column that I would like to reference contains duplicates, but the data in the adjacent columns is different.

To give an example, assume I had a spreadsheet of sales transactions.  One column would be the Customer ID, and the adjacent columns would contain the quantity, the cost per unit, total cost, order ID, etc.

What I would want to do in this case would be to select all the transactions with the same Customer ID and add them together based on their Order ID.  Then, I would want to print the result to a second sheet.

I realize that I can use built-in functions to accomplish this, but I would also like to format this report evenually using VBA.  Also, since I will have a variable number of rows that differ from one report to the next, I haven't encountered a fucnction that will allow you to add rows.

I'm assuming this must be done with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it manually, but it would take ages.  So VBA would be good, particularly as you would be able to generate future reports quickly.

My interpretation of what your saying is that each row in your report will be the total for one customer ID.  If it's something else, I imagine the below will still be mostly relevant.

I think it would be a bit much to give you the full answer, particularly as you haven't provided full detail but to take a stab at what you'd do:

1. Create your empty report page, whether it be a new worksheet or a new workbook
2. Loop through the table (probably using While next is not empty)

   a. Identifying if a row is for a customer ID you haven't covered yet

   i. If so then add a new entry in your report

   ii. Else add it to the existing customer ID record (loop through until you find it)
3. Format your report so it looks pretty, e.g:

   a. Fill the background in white

   b. Throw in some filled bars

   c. Put in good titles and totals etc.

For part 1, it might be better building an array first and then dumping the contents into the report.  It depends how process intensive it will be - if very intense, an array should shave off time.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of.  Basically building a bunch of arrays to track the data.  But, let's say I wanted to sum all totals for any given year by one customer.  This way, I can figure out which customers spent the most money.  This is all hypothetical, but you see what I'm getting at.  Think of each row as a transaction, and in these cases you might want to check all sales for a given year to figure out what your total was for that year, or for a particular client, or you may want to pull up a past order for review, etc.  Would using a bunch of arrays be the best approach?

Comment: @Addikt To clarify, you are looking to find the total amount spent for each customer or for one customer?  Also, I'd want to minimise the number of arrays (thinking the whole 'normalisation' concept from databases), what would each of your arrays be for?  Using arrays should be fastest as it saves writing to cells until the final bit.  The method I described uses the actual cells to calculate the workings, which will be a bit slower but might be easier to code.

Comment: The concept that I'm driving toward is that I would like to create these customized reports on the fly.  This is easy to do with a database since you can just create SQL queries to embed in your code.  When you are trying to do the same thing with an Excel dataset instead, this doesn't appear to be possible.  I imagine that I can use arrays to hold the values easy enough.  What I'm having an issue with, however, is being able to isolate the data that I want.  It's not as easy as SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...

Comment: Not sure if this has been covered above but I find the following always useful while building a similar system in VBA. Externalize the input to your VBA modules. I always have a separate "config" sheet that gives you the parameters of such a function. For instance you can have cells specified such "CustomerID" and "Year". A predefined value like "0" or blank cell can depict that this filter should not be applied. You can drill down as much as possible, but eventually you will have to perform comparisons in your VBA code to build the report.

Comment: Just to extend my comments, you can extend the features in "config" as much as you want, based on the amount of time you have as well as the amount of flexibility required by your utility.

Comment: @Aziz, what do you mean by externalize the input?  Are you referring to keeping the raw data in a separate file and then creating a data souce connection within Excel to reference the values?  I thought of this originally, but I cannot figure out how to automate it.  I don't know if it would be possible, but is there any way you could reference an example of something like this?  If you are suggesting what I think you, this sounds like it might be exactly what I'm looking for.  But, this would require that I spend a chunk of time learning how to do this.  I'm not a coder by trade.

Comment: @Addikt Going between SQL and VBA is quite challenging as the approach is completely different.  Why not consider an Access solution?  It does sound like an Access problem.  Anyway I think it would still be possible using Excel and VBA.  If you posted an explicit description of your "tables", and the report you want to generate (a mock-SQL style would be helpful), then we could probably give better help.

Comment: @Addikt by "externalize the input", I meant to say not to keep anything hardcoded within the code and put it in a separate worksheet - a "configurations"/"parameters" worksheet if you will. Before creating the reports you read what the parameters are and based on that generate your report. As an example you can have Name parameter set to "John" and year parameter set as blank to generate all the sales for John. Similarly a parameter combination of "John" and "2012" should generate John's sales for year 2012.

Comment: @Aziz, I see what you mean.  I thought you were referring to capturing the data in a separate file and then estbalishing a data connection to it.  I was planning to have a separate configuration tab rather than hard-coding the values.

Comment: @andrewb, I cannot use Access as I do not have access to it.  Also, this would add an extra step in the process since I would have to import the Excel data, create the relevant tables and then automate the whole thing using VBA anyway.